# Load XML into PHP - Weather

Tags: php, xml, weather

I have to load XML file about weather

```
api.yr.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=55.5575760;lon=9.3124340
```

in to PHP.

The XML file contains many information, I dont know how to start, can anyone tel me how to start ?

Comment: Use simplexml_load_string with curl/ file_get_contents / fopen( if remote fopen allowed ) after that you should do $result = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url)))); And then print_r($result) to see the structure. From that you probably know how to get values from an array. Json encode && decode are necessary for getting rid of these nested simplexml objects. This is just an easy hack to get xml to a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: But that means you loose XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start is to fetch die XML.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("api.yr.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=55.5575760;lon=9.3124340"));
```

Then read the documentation how to get informations from that file.

http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php

Comment: I hardly understand php.net, could you help me out with the start ?